# MS Access Combo Box fuzzy search

Tags: ms-access, vba

I wrote a combo box fuzzy search that almost works.
Problem? When I type 2 characters, it only sees 1.

Here's my code from the combo box in the "KeyPress" event.

```
Private Sub cmbBASELINE_SEARCH_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
       Dim strSQL As String


        strSQL = "SELECT tbl_COB_CAT.COB_ID, tbl_COB_CAT.BASELINE " _
               & "FROM tbl_COB_CAT " _
               & "WHERE tbl_COB_CAT.BASELINE Like '*" & Me.cmbBASELINE_SEARCH.Text & "*'" _
               & "ORDER BY tbl_COB_CAT.BASELINE; "



        Debug.Print strSQL


               Select Case KeyAscii
               Case 65 To 90, 48 To 57, 8 ' A-Z, 0-9 and backspace
               'Let these key codes pass through
                   Me.cmbBASELINE_SEARCH.RowSource = strSQL
                   Me.cmbBASELINE_SEARCH.Dropdown


               Case 97 To 122, 8, 127 'a-z, backspace and delete
               'Let these key codes pass through
                   Me.cmbBASELINE_SEARCH.RowSource = strSQL
                   Me.cmbBASELINE_SEARCH.Dropdown
               Case Else
               'All others get trapped
                   KeyAscii = 0 ' set ascii 0 to trap others input
               End Select


End Sub
```

For example, if I type "CAB" it searches for *CA*
If I type "25" it searches for *2*

What do I need to do to get it to be more accurate?
Also, if I erase the text in the combo box, it should make all of the values that were narrowed down - reappear in the drop down, but I have to hit "backspace" one more time to make the filtered list return to normal.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you're using the KeyPress event, rather than the KeyUp event; When you use keypress, the key pressed is not theoretically yet added to the Text in the control - you've trapped it beforehand.

And therefore I would assume that your debug.print SQL statement's output reflects this.

I would suggest then that instead of what you've got, you need to do it like this:

```
Private Sub cmbBASELINE_SEARCH_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    Dim strSQL As String
    dim valu   as string: valu = ""

    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case 65 To 90, 48 To 57, 97 To 122, 8, 127 'A-Z, a-z, 0-9, BS & Del
            'Let these key codes pass through
            valu = cboBASELINE_SEARCH.Text & chr(KeyAscii)
        Case Else 
            'All others get trapped
            KeyAscii = 0 ' set ascii 0 to trap others input
            Exit Sub
    End Select

    strSQL = "SELECT COB_ID, BASELINE FROM tbl_COB_CAT " _
           & "WHERE BASELINE LIKE '*" & valu & "*' ORDER BY 2"

    Me.cmbBASELINE_SEARCH.RowSource = strSQL
    Me.cmbBASELINE_SEARCH.Dropdown

    Debug.Print strSQL
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like it!  Functions exactly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could simply use the `Change` event of the textbox and use its `.Text` property in that event procedure. I see no reason to trap single keystrokes individually by hand.

Nitpick: There is nothing fuzzy about your search, it's a regular fulltext search.